# ConstraintLayout AutoTransition animation not working

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to animate constraints change.

My layout is:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/workspaceOverviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/loopScrollLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#990000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@null"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/workspaceOverviewVp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loopScrollLayout" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@null">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/indicatorsLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:background="#000099" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/settingsLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#009900" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Code is:

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
            .apply {
                clone(workspaceOverviewLayout)

                clear(R.id.loopScrollLayout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
                clear(R.id.bottomLayout, ConstraintSet.TOP)

                connect(R.id.loopScrollLayout, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP)
                connect(R.id.bottomLayout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
            }

        val transition = AutoTransition()
            .apply {
                duration = overviewAnimationDuration // 10_000L
                interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
            }

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(workspaceOverviewLayout, transition)
        constraintSet.applyTo(workspaceOverviewLayout)
```

Constraints are applied correctly, but just instantly, without any animation.

I use ConstraintLayout `2.0.2` (also tried with `2.0.1`) on Android 10.

Comment: Idk but for better Animation results use `ConstrainLayout` inside `coordinatorlayout `, i personally use it for any kind of animation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue was that I was trying to change `workspaceOverviewLayout`'s visibility and apply the `ConstraintSet` right after it.

This two operations should be ran in different layout passes, so to fix it I need just to do this:

```
    private fun enterOverviewMode() {
        workspaceOverviewLayout.isVisible = true
        workspaceVp.isVisible = false

        workspaceOverviewLayout.post { // Post to «delay» the constraint change
            animateEnterOverviewMode()
        }
```